cannot access own properties in javascript constructor
I have a base class and another that extends it, how can I access fields in the constructor?
class BaseModel {
    constructor() {
        console.log('no fields :(')
        console.log(this.fields)
        this.fields.map((field) => {
            field.label = field.label || field.name;
        })
    }
}

class UserModel extends BaseModel {
    fields = [
        { name: 'id' },
        { name: 'name' },
        { name: 'email' },
    ];
    constructor(name, email) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}

const user = new UserModel('bob', 'me@bob.com');
console.log(user);

I went about 2 pages deep and didn't find a satisfactory answer of how to set this up. The best I found was to set a timeout in the constructor which seemed wrong.

Have you seen: ES6, access props set by the child from the parent's constructor?

I messed with this for a bit longer and came up with a pretty reasonable solution.  Feels like the least best of a bunch of not so great options.
If you just rename the constructor on BaseModel to init(), then call super().init() in the child class it works fine, same w/ models 2-deep, could use more testing but seems like a decent solve for now.
class BaseModel {
    init() {
        console.log('fields!')
        console.log(this.fields)
        this.fields.map((field) => {
            field.label = field.label || field.name;
        })
    }
}

class UserModel extends BaseModel {
    fields = [
        { name: 'id' },
        { name: 'name' },
        { name: 'email' },
    ];
    constructor(name, email) {
        super().init();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class ModeratorModel extends UserModel {
    fields = [
        { name: 'id' },
        { name: 'name' },
        { name: 'email' },
        { name: 'permissions' },
    ];
    constructor(name, email, permissions) {
        super().init();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }
    getPermissions() {
        return this.permissions;
    }
}

const user = new UserModel('bob', 'me@bob.com');
console.log(user);

const moderator = new ModeratorModel('jim', 'me@jim.com', 'all');
console.log(moderator);
console.log(moderator.getPermissions());


In new ModeratorModel, init is called twice

For readability you can replace super().init(); with super();\n this.init() to avoid the appearance of doing something strange. Also suggest changing the two fields.map calls to fields.map for the same reason.

If you want to access fields in the parent constructor sync you should pass the fields to it:


class BaseModel {
    constructor(fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
        console.log(this.fields)
        this.fields.map((field) => {
            field.label = field.label || field.name;
        })
    }
}

class UserModel extends BaseModel { 
    constructor(name, email) {
        super([
            { name: 'id' },
            { name: 'name' },
            { name: 'email' },
        ]);
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}

const user = new UserModel('bob', 'me@bob.com');
console.log(user);




unfortunately this makes for pretty ugly code, and requires an ever-growing list of things passed to the constructor which quickly gets out of hand, as I really want access to ALL the child class properties

@blented Why would it do that? Your parent class constructor should have no business with the child class properties.

@Bergi if I want to do init stuff on those properties, like add missing labels, I for some reason have to pass EVERY property on the child class to the base class that I want to mess with?  that seems worse than a custom init function..

@blented If you only want to fill in labels, write a static helper function: fields = BaseModel.createFields([ … ]);. No need to involve the constructor at all. There are many possible solutions, but I don't fully understand your use case (your question is missing the code that is actually accessing the .fields property, or any justification for using class inheritance) so I didn't write an answer.
